# kSOAP 2 Android

Tags: android

I don't know why am i not able to get this?....maybe i am missing something or am plain dumb

I want trying to call webservice from a Android App

Now to do this came across that kSOAP 2 for Android is the library that would be needed

However, i see many guys in many posts pointing that one would have to **include the jar for ksoap2 for android platform in eclipse**

But which jar to include ?

At "http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/" i see a link to git source where entire source is there.....so is it that i take files needed and make a jar out of it.

Also i see many guys saying to include the jar file ending with "-dependencies"....however, downloading such a file seems to be an issue....i just don't get the file with correct size.

So, which is the jar file to include in eclipse for calling webservices w.r.t. kSOAp 2 ?

Thanks
Yogurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include file:  ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar'  My file is 142 KB, or 145,350 bytes.  You don't need to make the jar directly, it can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.5.2/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar).

Also, this [video here](http://vimeo.com/9633556)
you'll probably fine quite helpful.

Comment: Is it me.....or....The link seems to be same as on frontpage of "http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/" . I only get a HTML doc and not a jar file....again is it just me ?

Comment: If the page loads, click 'view raw file' on the bottom of the right pane.  That will allow you to download the .jar directly.

Comment: Thanks...that helped. Now trying a to play around with the library. Trying to fetch data from a public webservice. Following is the code.

Comment: SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Celsius","32");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;
     soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        final HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  transportSE.debug = false;        transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION,soapEnvelope); Object result=soapEnvelope.getResponse(); And have following statement in AndroidManifest.xml   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: which would primarily let me send/receive data as saw in one of other posts.   However, i get a "java.net.socketexception : the operation timed out". Any thoughts? what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Eclipse or some other IDE? You can use the project properties and add this JAR as dependency.

Go here:
http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/

Or: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/

And there is a download link.

Comment: It seems at "http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/" the file is for J2ME....will it work w.r.t. Android ?

Comment: Have a try. J2ME is basically a subset and SOAP should not use any special functions. `Magua`s link seems to be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

The How to Use wiki page of the project I wrote explains if for using a Maven as well as an Ant or Eclipse based build.

For Eclipse usage you basically download the jar with dependencies by clicking on the "View Raw File" link and put it into the lib folder of your app project. If that folder does not exist you have to add it. Then you have to add it to the classpath in Eclipse and you are done.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse